# RapidSMS tutorial 2, handling a message

Tags: python, django, sms

Am a newbie to Django right now working my way through the Rapidsms [tutorial](http://rapidsms.readthedocs.org/en/develop/tutorial/tutorial02.html#tutorial02) and am having trouble with page 2 in the tutorial.

The message tester does not recognize the "Help" command even after coding the myhandlers.py and adding the necessary changes to settings.py.   The myhandlers.py is under the tut folder.

The ping-pong command works fine so the message tester is working fine. 
Here is the relevant code.

```
myhandlers.py

from rapidsms.contrib.handlers import KeywordHandler

help_text = {
    'aaa': 'Help for aaa',
    'bbb': 'Help for bbb',
    'ccc': 'Help for ccc',
}


class HelpHandler(KeywordHandler):
    keyword = "help"

    def help(self):
        """Invoked if someone just sends `HELP`.  We also call this
        from `handle` if we don't recognize the arguments to HELP.
        """
        self.respond("Allowed commands are AAA, BBB, and CCC. Send "
                     "HELP <command> for more help on a specific command.")

    def handle(self, text):
        """Invoked if someone sends `HELP <any text>`"""
        text = text.strip().lower()
        if text == 'aaa':
            self.respond(help_text['aaa'])
        elif text == 'bbb':
            self.respond(help_text['bbb'])
        elif text == 'ccc':
            self.respond(help_text['ccc'])
        else:
            self.help()


Now, add “rapidsms.contrib.handlers” to INSTALLED_APPS:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "rapidsms.contrib.handlers",
    ...
]

and add your new class to RAPIDSMS_HANDLERS:

RAPIDSMS_HANDLERS = [
    ...
    "myhandlers.HelpHandler",
    ...
]
```

Comment: @Daniel, Could you add "rapidsms" to the group of allowed tags. I was unable to tag it onto this and yet it's quite a widely used software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check your `rapidsms_tut/rapidsms.log` file for more information about errors loading handlers.
- Make sure that your `myhandlers.py` is in the same directory as your manage.py (or else change `RAPIDSMS_HANDLERS` to point to `rapidsms_tut.myhandlers` or wherever you've placed the file.
- For more information and other problems, it might be best to contact the [RapidSMS community](http://rapidsms.org/community) directly.

Comment: Dear @ablemann, 
Thanks for the tip. It worked. Apparently, I had put my myhandlers.py in the wrong place. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings files it is supposed to be

listed as follows

RAPIDSMS_HANDLERS = [
    ...
    "the_application.myhandlers.HelpHandler",
    ...
]